# iptables - how to allow internet but block subnet?

Tags: iptables

How to isolate one computer in network

> IP to isolation: 10.17.15.99
>
> Subnet: 10.17.15.0
>
> Gateway: 10.15.15.1

Tried:

`iptables -I INPUT -s 10.17.15.99 -d 10.17.0.0/24 -j DROP`

I need to:

- Access to internet from the .99 IP
- Access to from subnet to it
- Drop all connections to subnet from the IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow traffic from the subnet `10.17.0.0/24` to `10.17.15.99`, but not allow traffic the other way, this gets a little tricky. The problem is when `10.17.15.99` responds to traffic from `10.17.0.0/24`, it needs to be allowed.

You can solve this conundrum with iptables state tracking. The idea is to block new connections outbound from the box, but allow them inbound. To start with, some recommended reading is: http://www.iptables.info/en/connection-state.html#USERLANDSTATES

Thus this one rule should handle it:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.17.15.99 -d 10.17.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

Note that the above rule is meant to be placed on the gateway/router which handles traffic for that `10.17.15.99` box. The only other option is to put the filter on the box itself, in which case you should change the `FORWARD` to `OUTPUT`.

Note that the `state` module has support for UDP as well, so it should work there too, and not just TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Your `iptables ... DROP`-rule looks good, except that the subnet you've specified is not the one you want to block access to?

If you want more detailed help, you should describe your network better.